# custom circular slider control in iPhone with images

Tags: ios, iphone, custom-controls, circular-slider

i have been trying to develop custom control(circular Slider with image) in iPhone can someone guide me whether this implementation possible in iPhone if we can achieve this then how can we implement this

Thanks in advance.
- Surya

Comment: you can refere this link: < https://github.com/ariok/TB_CircularSlider >

Comment: Thanks for your response i am looking for semi circular slider control like below(refer link) is there a way to modify above code and get my design 
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ml12ti&s=8#.UvSgg_mSyYI